# ADODB Command Execute method fails without an error when retried

Tags: sql, vb6, adodb

I'm working on some code that uses a data layer for CRUD operations. It uses an ADODB Command object to execute T-SQL statements that may be stored procedures, functions, or inline SQL. It initially uses the default CommandTimeout of 30 seconds. The database it MS SQL. In the error handler the Timeout error, -2147217871 is caught and the CommandTimeout value is doubled up to 3 times. So the first time the CommandTimeout is set to 60 seconds, the second time it is set to 120 seconds, then 240 seconds. After updating the CommandTimeout a Resume statement resumes execution at the Execute method.

The problem I am having is an update stored procedure is hitting the CommandTimeout at 30 seconds. The error handler updates the CommandTimeout to 60 seconds and sets the execution back to the Execute method. The Execute method completes without error, but the database record is not updated. I tried changing the CommandTimeout to 0, infinite, so as I was stepping through the code I wouldn't have to step through the error handler and suddenly the update worked. Setting the CommandTimeout back caused the update to fail again. I've seen this error handler work many times succesfully. This is the first time I've seen this behavior. Does anyone know what the problem is?

```
'timeout error, retry after doubling the timeout
If (Err.Number = -2147217871) And iRetryCount < iMaxRetrys Then
    iRetryCount = iRetryCount + 1
    spCmd.CommandTimeout = spCmd.CommandTimeout * 2
    LocalTimer = Timer
    Do While Timer < LocalTimer + 0.5    '.5 seconds
        'just wait
    Loop
    Err.Clear
    spCmd.ActiveConnection.Errors.Clear
    Resume
```

Comment: If you are getting a timeout during SQL execution, I wonder if just increasing the command timeout is the right direction?  Your SQL operation is apparently doing some heavy lifting, or contending for locked resources.  Having the client just say "whoops, times-up, let me loop back around and ask you to do do that again" seems counter-productive.  Further, if you were in the middle of a transaction when this happens, the connection may still have that transaction open.  Consider closing and reopening a new connection in this case,

Comment: I'd concur with tcarvin's comments.  Additionally, the last request would have a timeout of 240 seconds, as noted in the post.  So if 240 seconds is an acceptable period of time to wait before timing out, just set the CommandTimeout to 240 seconds, and don't do any retries for timeout exceptions.

Comment: When the update query does work (only when the timeout setting is 0 seconds?), how long does it take to run?

Comment: @MarkL The particular query I am testing runs in approx. 39 seconds. I have been trying to optimize the query and have gotten it to as little as approx. 20 seconds.

Comment: @tcarvin, While I'm open to modifying the error handler and I agree with increasing the timeout overall, this particular error handler has been in place and working for years and suggesting any change to it is going to met with resistance.

Comment: @tcarvin It's highly unlikely a transaction will survive ADODB Command timeout. Client timeout is baked into MSSQL, it's not implemented only in ADODB w/ timers or similar.

Comment: A quote from https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4a1fc2d0-8e3d-49c7-8b21-294b9a197a18/adonet-sql-transaction-not-rolled-back-on-timeout?forum=adodotnetdataproviders - "One ugly thing about timeouts is that after the command is cancelled by the client, the transaction remains open unless the SET XACT_ABORT ON session setting is on. If you add SET XACT_ABORT ON to the procs or issue the command after opening each connection, SQL Server will rollback the transaction automatically after a timeout (and most other errors), even if the client doesn't explicitly rollback. "

Comment: @tcarvin True! One must always SET XACT_ABORT ON after connection is open which is unfortunately not set by default or bad things can happen with transactions upon error.